# How to call SuperClass delegate method from SubClass delegate method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, delegates

I have a `SuperClass` that implements `<UIWebViewDelegate>`, in this class I implemented the method `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`

```
@interface SuperClass
...
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request1 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
     // SuperClass treatment
}
...
@end
```

Then I have a `SubClass` that extend this `SuperClass`. the `SubClass` implements `<UIWebViewDelegate>` too, and the method `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` as well :

```
@interface SubClass: SuperClass
...
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request1 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
     // SubClass treatment
}
...
@end
```

The code works for me, because I need to do a specific treatment for the `SubClass`.
But in a specific case, I need to call the `SuperClass` `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` method.

**I need the delegate to execute the `SuperClass` `UIWebViewDelegate` methods.**

I tried to use `super` to call the `SuperClass` method, but with no use!

Is that possible?

Comment: Use [self.super webView: webView  shouldStartLoadWithRequest: request1 navigationType: navigationType];

Comment: Thanks @ReshmiMajumder but it's not working!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SuperClass**

```
@interface ViewController () <UIWebViewDelegate>
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request1 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType 
{    
  NSLog(@"superview");
  return true;    
}
```

**Subclass (ViewController1.m)**

```
@interface ViewController1 () <UIWebViewDelegate>
    
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webview;

@end

@implementation ViewController1

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request1 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

     NSLog(@"subclass");
     [super webView:webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request1 navigationType:navigationType];
     return true;

 }

- (IBAction)action:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"loading");
    [_webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.co.in"]]];

 }
```

In the logs it is coming as:

> 2016-06-29 17:51:39.807 Test[31575:8224563] loading
>
> 2016-06-29 17:51:41.008 Test[31575:8224563] subclass
>
> 2016-06-29 17:51:41.008 Test[31575:8224563] superview

Comment: Do I have to put the methods declaration in `SuperClass.h` ? Because I m having the error `No visible @interface for 'SuperClass' declares the selector 'webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:'`

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I still getting the same error, could you plz share the project with me?

Comment: It worked, `<UIWebViewDelegate>` is needed on the `SuperClass` too

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface SuperClass
- (void)handleWebViewShouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request;

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
     [self handleWebViewShouldStartLoadWithRequest:request];
}

@end
```

In the `handleWebViewShouldStartLoadWithRequest:` of subclass, you can call `[super handleWebViewShouldStartLoadWithRequest:request]`;

Comment: Thanks, I thought about this solution, but is there a way that the delegate call SuperClass UIWebViewDelegate methods.?

Comment: In short, I think no.